# Почему нельзя вывести виджеты?

Tags: python, ооп, классы, методы, pyqt6

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
import sys


class MyApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __int__(self, parent):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label_for_menu = QtWidgets.QLabel('Привет!')
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Перейти в главное меню')
        self.exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выйти')
        self.enter_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.enter_box.addWidget(self.label_for_menu)
        self.enter_box.addWidget(self.menu)
        self.enter_box.addWidget(self.exit)
        self.setLayout(self.enter_box)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.setWindowTitle('Мои настройки')
    window.resize(250, 250)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Просто выводит окно без виджетов, она как будто обходит класc `MyApp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
#from PyQt6 import QtWidgets                                          # PyQt6
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets                                           # PyQt5


class MyApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):
#    def __int__(self, parent):
#        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    def __init__(self):                                                # +++
        super().__init__()                                             # +++
        
        self.label_for_menu = QtWidgets.QLabel('Привет!')
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Перейти в главное меню')
        self.exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выйти')
        
        self.enter_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.enter_box.addWidget(self.label_for_menu)
        self.enter_box.addWidget(self.menu)
        self.enter_box.addWidget(self.exit)
        self.setLayout(self.enter_box)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.setWindowTitle('Мои настройки')
    window.resize(250, 250)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое. Только я не понял ошибки, я только что начал разбирать  Ваш код, и мой 
 в изначальный код вследствии начал работать. Короче, я ничего не понял - мне нужно поспать))))